# npm install failing. Cloud 9 ide

Tags: node.js, express, cloud9-ide, npm-install

I am having the same issue with npm. Tried on my pc tried to avoid directory issues and getting the same issues on cloud9 . Hoping it being on a virtual machine there would be little i could do to mess it up, i have tried private:true  and falsi and completely without it. As well as sockt.io "latest" same with express. Any insight would be great

```
{ "name": "chit",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "description": "chat practice",
 "private": "false",
 "dependencies":{ "socket.io":"1.4.8",
 "express":"4.14.0" }
 "author": "Charles",
 "license": "ISC"
```

Thank you so much

See error

```
ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-c9
npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! file /home/ubuntu/workspace/chat/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token 'a' at 10:4
npm ERR!   "author": "Charles",
npm ERR!    ^
npm ERR! File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/chat/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/chat/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon here:

> ```
> { "name": "chit",
> "version": "0.0.1",
> "description": "chat practice",
> "private": "false",
> "dependencies":{ "socket.io":"1.4.8",
> "express":"4.14.0" } // <--- missing colon here
> "author": "Charles",
> "license": "ISC"
> ```

It should be:

```
{
    "name": "chit",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "chat practice",
    "private": "false",
    "dependencies": {
        "socket.io": "1.4.8",
        "express": "4.14.0"
    },
    "author": "Charles",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Hello Quill thank you so much. I was under the impression node did not like any lingering commas.

Comment: @Darth Node wants JSON files to be perfect, but the actual JavaScript code doesn't need to be perfect most of the time